# A mesh gets distorted for no clear reason

Tags: mesh

I'm actually a novice in Blender so this may be disgustingly easy to solve - but here's the problem. I'm trying to combine two XPS models, put some meshes from model one to model two and... Got this weird distortion in attempt to pose it. I know that I 'moved' the bone instead of 'rotating' it, but the main problem is these two sections of the model's leg which just won't move after their respective bone. How do I apply the working leg's behavior to the problematic leg?

[image]

Comment: you probably need to correct this in Weight Paint mode

Comment: @moonboots Gonna try it, thank you! But is there anything like the classic 'eyedropper' tool in blender? Or probably a possibility to copy the weights from one mesh to another?

Comment: what do you mean exactly? Not in Weight Paint mode, but you can get the exact weight of a vertex in the N panel if that's what you want?

Comment: @moonboots welp, what I want is get rid of the distortion :D I tried to 'transfer weights' but this made the distorted leg completely straight and irresponsive to the bone at all. I opened the N tab and all the settings are the same there. Can't find any mentions of weights there though.

Comment: so you've used the Data Trasfer modifier? It should work... Anyway the quickest way is to switch to Weight Paint mode, but maybe before that go in Edit mode, select this part of you mesh, then in the Properties panel > Object Data > Vertex Groups, on the dropdown menu on the right of the list (down arrow), click on Remove From All Groups, so that these vertices are not affected by any bones

Comment: Welp, at the end of the day nothing changed :(

Comment: I also tried the 'data transfer' thing, just moved all working leg's properties to the broken one - and it changed nothing.

Comment: Also tried painting the weights myself. The leg's all red but doesn't reach the place where it has to be.

Comment: maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Done https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/O21Z1XXM/

Thank you!

Comment: In the Properties panel > Object Data > Skeleton > Skeleton > Layers, you have bones on the second layer that weight on your mesh, what are they supposed to do?

Comment: I don't know, honestly. I suppose this could happen after merging two armatures together but I'm not sure.

Comment: Well, you also need to check the weight that thay have on your mesh, actually your problem is just a problem of weight, you need to display this second layer, switch your mesh to Weight Paint mode and check these bones as well

Comment: Also understand what these bones are for

Comment: Tell you what, this layer is actually a whole other armature consisting of 'unused' bones which kept getting in my way while I was messing around with, hm, 'used' bones. I got rid of it as well as the redundant layers and- - the leg is still misbehaving :c